# How to return the value/status on Push Method in Nativescript + Firebase Database?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript

I would like to return the status (`OK or NOT_OK`) in register method of `UserService.ts`.
Is there way to put return statement in `push` method of `firebase database + nativescript`?

AppComponent.ts

```
....

export class AppComponent {
...
  signUp() {
    var result = this.userService.register(this.user);
    if(result == "OK") {
      alert("Your account was successfully created.");
      this.toggleDisplay();
    } else if(result == "NOT_OK") {
      alert("Unfortunately we were unable to create your account.");
    }
  }
}
```

UserService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { User } from "./user";

const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  register(user : User) {       
    firebase.push('/users', user).then(
      function (result) {
        console.log("created key: " + result.key);
        -> here I cannot write like -> return "OK"
      },      
      function (error) {
        console.log("Error ... : " + error);
        -> here I cannot write like -> return "NOT_OK"
      }      
    );          
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `async/await` Or convert promise into Observable using `fromPromise` and convert the values using `map` operator.